# cant call powershell GUI script from unc path from a GUI

Tags: powershell, unc

I have a powershell GUI that launches a secound ps1 file (a GUI as well) it works fine and passes the argu on to the second one without a problem when its on the C: drive 
im trying to use it with a UNC path of \share\service desk\sdtools.ps1
but it does not open

The below works

```
Function login {

$sdnum = $numInputBox.text

Start-Process "powershell.exe" -windowstyle hidden -ArgumentList "-File C:\servicedesk\sdtool.ps1 -a $sdnum"

#Close login-form so the first script will finish.
$form.Close()

}
```

The below never launches the second file

```
Function login {

$sdnum = $numInputBox.text

Start-Process "powershell.exe" -windowstyle hidden -ArgumentList "-File \\share\service desk\sdtool.ps1 -a $sdnum"

#Close login-form so the first script will finish.
$form.Close()

}
```

i think it is how i have encapsulated the file name but i have tried many ways and none with luck it can open the file as a text document so i do manage to get it to call the file but not to run in powershell(i have also tried it with the full path to powershell and that dosnt work)

as \share\service desk\sdtool.ps1 is the same as g:\service desk\sdtool.ps1 i have also tried that with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space in the path, so you need to encapsulate it in quotes:

```
Start-Process "powershell.exe" -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "-File `"\\share\service desk\sdtool.ps1`" -a $sdnum"
```

Comment: Hi your first way give me "the string is missing a terminator: '. and the second still dosnt open the file.

Comment: ah it does call the gui if i remove -windowstyle hidden but i need to hide the background command window when it runs if i put it back in it dosnt open But it dosnt pass the argument to the second scrypt

Comment: Yes, that `-windowstyle hidden` parameter doesn't like GUIs, I also have the same problem when testing.

Comment: OK, maybe a solution. I used the -NoNewWindow switch

Comment: top man now working (the argument didnt pass as i had typed wrong name) so now its working as should thank you :)

Comment: @MaxBayliss, you've used my solution (other question) wrong. :) My answer had the `-WindowStyle Hidden` inside the argumentlist like `-ArgumentList "-WindowStyle Hidden -File ..."`. The `-WindowStyle` parameter of the `Start-Process`-cmdlet doesn't work, but the parameter also exists in the `powershell.exe` and that works.

Comment: @FrodeF. i used it as per your post and it worked until i used it with the UNC path.

Comment: It works with both UNC and local paths (tested). The problem with not quoting a path that includes whitespace is not related to powershell, unc or any parameters, as that's just how OSes works. :) I had to comment on this because @MickyBalladelli said that `-WindowStyle Hidden` doesn't work with GUIs, which is partly wrong: My WindowStyle-answer works (`powershell.exe`-argument), while the sample you gave Micky does not (cmdlet-parameter). :)

Answer (score 0):

below is the full ps1 file i am using

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(230,75)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.Text = "Please Login"
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,5) 
$Label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55,20) 
$Label.Text = "Staff no:"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label) 
$numInputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$numInputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,5) 
$numInputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,26) 
$numInputBox.text = ""
$numInputBox.add_Keydown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
{login}})
$form.Controls.Add($numInputBox)

Function login {

$sdnum = $numInputBox.text

#Start-Process "powershell.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList "-File ‘”\\share\Service              Desk\sdtool.ps1`" -a $sdnum"
Start-Process "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-File `"\\share\Service Desk\sdtool.ps1`" -a         $sdnum"
$Form.Close()

}

$loginbutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$loginbutton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,21)
$loginbutton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(115,4)
$loginbutton.add_click({login})
$loginbutton.Text = "Login"
$form.Controls.Add($loginbutton)
$drc = $form.ShowDialog()
```